# Script to update database.php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I need to create a command that automatically updates from the database.php file in Laravel. For example, create automatic entries:

```
'emp001' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'emp001'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
'emp002' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'emp002'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
...
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to dynamically create database connections? Maybe it could be solved in a different way?

Comment: @Das's question is a good one. There's frequently a better way. Are you looking to build some sort of multi-tenant system?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to this would be to add/modify your configurations in the `AppServiceProvider`:

```
config(['database.connections.emp001' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'emp001'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
]]);
```

Comment: Having done this, be careful. If any queries have already been run prior to changing the config, this has no effect (as Laravel uses the already-established connection). It may be safer to add a *new* database connection to the config and use it instead.

Comment: exact, but how do I do this. Because I need a connection for different user types

Comment: @spiderman123 Why do you need separate databases for different user types? A role system is usually a better approach. Even if you really do, chances are you don't need it dynamically - you could create multiple connections and use different ones for different models. Regardless, it would help immensely if you updated your question with more info on what you're trying to accomplish.